# Comparing variations of A*

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, artificial-intelligence, search-algorithms, empirical-research

I am running some experiments with a maze, and trying different variations of A*. Based on my experiments, I have been able to form some opinion (that at least in those cases, graph checking is better than IDA).

I am looking for online articles that have done similar experiments, comparing variations of A* with respect to expanded nodes, but have not come across anything concrete.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Could you refer some online articles or tutorials that compare variations of A*? This is my question :)

Comment: What do you mean by _variations of A*_?  Are you talking about different heuristics, data structure or something else?

Comment: one variation is Iterative Deepening A* (IDA). Another is graph search A*. All are variations of the algorithm A*. All applied to the same problem, to be able to compare.

Comment: @MartinH.L. In that case you don't want to compare A* and IDA* since A* always beats IDA* (when paths are at least two steps).  IDA* is only sensible over A* if you care about memory.  (Ps [meta]:  If you use the @-symbol and name when you reply to a comment, the one with that name is informed about your reply.)

Comment: @Pål GD Thanks, could you also explain about A* variation that checks cycles and avoids them? I think they are called A* graph search. How does that compare to the other two?

Comment: @MartinH.L. Do you have access to AI: A Modern Approach (AIMA) by Russel & Norvig?  Possibly via a library?  I would check out that book, they have a very nice explanation of the differences between graph and tree search.  The issue about graph search is that you have to store which nodes you have visited, and this takes $O(n)$ memory, in order to not revisit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a lot of bibliography on whether one algorithm is better than the other. In particular, the main insight is: "*in the presence of duplicates (e.g. grids), A$^*$ should be preferred, whereas in other cases IDA$^*$ should be in general preferred*". For example, heuristic planners usually prefer best-first search strategies such as A$^*$ instead of IDA$^*$ (just because duplicates occur in many domains). For example, to solve the $N$-Puzzle, the $N$-Pancake, or the TopSpin, IDA$^*$ is the current algorithm of choice. For other cases, such as Rubik's Cube or Towers of Hanoi, IDA$^*$ is still the algorithm of choice but be careful and try to implement a good strategy for handling symmetries. In the case of grids, A$^*$ is the right choice.

There is a wonderful paper about how to implement A$^*$ and makes a lot of considerations that, I think, fit your question: [Ethan Andrew Burns, Matthew Hatem, Michael J. Leighton, Wheeler Ruml. Implementing Fast Heuristic Search Code](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS12/paper/view/5404/5173)

Let me know, please, whether this helps or not,

Comment: I believe you're an expert on this field, could you help me understand why non-recursive IDA* is correct when it's implemented by DFS?

Comment: Do you mean DFS = depth-first search? I'm not sure I properly understood your question as the usual choice for implementing Depth-First search is to use a stack and recursive implementations provide one automatically. Thus, if you want to make a non-recursive implementation of Depth-First search all you need is to keep control of your own stack. IDA*, on the other hand, is a depth-first search variant so .. Sorry if I did not understood this question ...

Comment: Yes, I meant depth-first search, sorry for unclearness. Yes I know IDA* is a depth-first search variant, but my problem is that I want to prove the correctness of IDA*, and I have tried deduction from A*, but since A* is an extension of Dijkstra shortest path first algorithm, which is a BFS idea, I stuck.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, which is not my mother tongue. But I think my problem is well stated and if you have time please take a look: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133840/65033, this problem is important for me and I'm willing to provide bounty for this question.